# Gauss-Bonnet Theorem: Neither Gauss nor Bonnet

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ho.history-overview, curvature

Tristan Needham says (p.174),<sup>*</sup>

> "While Gauss and Bonnet certainly paved the road to [the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem],
> neither one of them was even aware of this extraordinary result, let alone stated it!"

Needham assigns the honor to Leopold Kronecker and Walther von Dyck.

(*Added*). By "the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem," Neeham means
$$\mathcal{K}(S_g) = 4 \pi (1-g) = 2 \pi \chi(S_g)$$
where $S_g$ is a closed, orientable surface of genus $g$,
$\mathcal{K}(S_g)$ is its total curvature,
and $\chi(S_g)$ is its Euler characteristic.

My question is:

> ***Q***. Is Needham's recounting historically accurate?

---

---

> <sup>*</sup> Needham, Tristan. *Visual Differential Geometry and Forms.* Princeton University Press, 2021.

Comment: Surely better for https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: The "classical" form of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem talks about the sum of angles of a geodesic triangle in terms of the integral of the curvature over it; this is a statement in differential *geometry*. However, in modern differential *topology* books it is usually stated as a relation between the Euler characteristic of a compact surface and the integral of the curvature over it. Perhaps this distinction is at play.

Comment: Perhaps Needham's statement stems from a relatively narrow reading of what the Gauss-Bonnet theorem is stating.  At its most broad, you could view Gauss-Bonnet as a statement of what the integral of the curvature over a 2-dimensional manifold (perhaps with corners) is, in terms of the curvature of the boundary curves (including jump angles) and the euler characteristic of the 2-dimensional manifold.  Gauss's version assuming the region is a geodesic triangle is one instance of the theorem, but it of course can be stated in greater generality.

Comment: A belated addition to explain what Needham means by "the Gauss-Bonnet theorem."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Shiing-Shen Chern's [Historical remarks on Gauss-Bonnet](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812812834_0033) seems an authoritative source. The [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#For_triangles) goes back to Gauss (1827), Bonnet (1848), and Binet (unpublished). Gauss considered a triangle, Bonnet and Binet generalized it to smooth
closed curves, where the sum of the angles is replaced by the integral of the geodesic curvature.

The [equation for compact surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#Statement) of arbitrary genus, referred to by Needham, was written up later by von Dyck (1888) (relying on earlier developments by Kronecker). So yes, the question in the OP "is Needham accurate" can be answered in the affirmative.

Daniel Gottlieb has examined the "sociology of mathematics" which governs the naming of theorems. In the context of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem he [writes](https://doi.org/10.2307/2974712): *Part of this story shows that the name of a theorem is not really for an
attribution. It is very convenient to have a name for important theorems, and the
main point is that people should know approximately what theorem is meant by
the name rather than who gets the credit. Still, one can reflect that Bonnet's name
is famous and Dyck's is virtually unknown these days.*

---

Because of Binet's independent work, some authors speak of the Gauss-Binet-Bonnet theorem, here is one [example.](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/LASIE/hal-03363070v1)

And here is the [footnote](https://books.google.nl/books?id=04R7tOWnt2oC&pg=RA2-PA129) by Bonnet, in which he credits Binet.

[image]

<sub>After having completed this paper, I saw a note by Binet, appended to a paper by Olinde Rodrigues in the "Correspondence of the École Polytechnique". In that note Binet derived Gauss's theorem in a similar way as I did.</sub>

Comment: Bonnet and Binet? That’s almost as confusing as Monet and Manet!

Comment: @SamHopkins: Don't forget Brunn and Debrunner, of Borromean link fame.

Comment: @RyanBudney: Or Leonhard Euler, of St Petersburg, Russia, and Lenny Euler, the owner of Euler's Liquor Lounge in St. Petersburg, Florida.